# Spacemacs - disable last ex command repeat on empty input

Tags: spacemacs, evil

On vim, an empty ex command (`:`) leads to a noop upon pressing `enter`.

On Spacemacs (or Evil in general maybe), it re-runs the last command.

Is there a variable I can tweak in my configuration to make Spacemacs behave like Vim in that regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.  This behavior is currently hardcoded in Evil.  If it causes great discomfort to you, feel free to hand in an enhancement request on the bug tracker.

Comment: In case someone is interested, I opened the following ticket: https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/issues/883